# ScrollView hides top elements of the layout

Tags: android, layout

I have pretty simple dialog layout and added scrollview because dialog can be quite long and not fit into the screen
When I initially run the dialog (it fits the screen) everything is fine, then I change device orientation to landscape, dialog does not fit to screen anymore, scrolling appears, but several top elements (up to @+id/addr_label) become invisible though some empty space appears between Title and first visible element exist. The most confusing thing is- when I change device back to portrait view- these elements are still invisible.

UPDATE: Just checked the case when phone is initially in landscape mode- in this case all elements are shown correctly. when I change it back to portrait- the elements disappear. seems to be a "change orientation" bug

What can be a problem?

Layout and screenshots are below (Android is 2.3.5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root22" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/details_ssid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/details_bssid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/latitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/longitude"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/addr_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/address_label" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/descr_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description_label" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_root" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/yes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:text= "@string/Yes"
        android:visibility="visible"
    />


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:text= "@string/No"
        android:visibility="visible"
    />  
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

Code is pretty boring:
onCreateDialog in Activity which sets layout and 
onPrepareDialog whic sets values to all these fields

onCreateDialog

```
    case CONFIRM_SHARE_AP:
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this){
            public void onBackPressed()
            {
                dismissDialog(CONFIRM_SHARE_AP);
            }
        };

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ap_add_confirmation);

        dialog.setTitle(R.string.confirm_share);

        Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dismissDialog(CONFIRM_SHARE_AP);

            }
        });
        return dialog;          
    }
```

onPrepareDialog
has nothing specific at all

http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/4642/devicev1.png

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/985/devicev2.png

Comment: IImages are too small and don't open. Try a more known server like imageshack for example. And don't resize it.

Comment: At first blush, I don't think it's a problem with the layout. I think it's a problem with the code that sets the contents of those views. You should post the relevant code.

Comment: have you try android:fillViewport="true" in scrollview?

Comment: dmon, Added code. I do not thing this is a reason because first time it is shown OK.                         Maneesh- tried-no luck

Answer (score 0):

Found a root of the prob.
This is because during orientation change activity is restarted (by default) and therefore dialogs are recreated.